# Daily cron job send email Webform submissions file

Tags: webforms

create an automatic excel extract of all requests and send it a specific email address every day.

How would I do this? Is there any existing Module to do this in Drupal 7?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view that shows the days submissions, use the data export module to convert it to excel, filter it by day (currrent day). Use rules module to send an email (not sure how to attach it, may need to send link). Not sure if this would work exactly how you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for this: [Webform Scheduled Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_scheduled_export)

From the project page:

> Allows you to schedule a webform submission export to run at a set
>   point in time and repeat on a daily, weekly or monthly basis. The
>   exports use all the options available to Webform's "Download" tab and
>   they're attached to the email sent to the configured users.